# Simple nested ul li menu with hover effect but issue regarding margin-top

Tags: jquery, css

my js:

```
$("#navShop li").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("ul.subCatMenu").stop(true, true).show();
},
function () {
    $(this).find("ul.subCatMenu").stop(true, true).hide();
});
```

Nothing special in the JS and in my HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="/" id="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="About">About</a>
        <ul class="subCatMenu">
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The thing is that the designer wants a line under about when you hover, so just an

```
a:hover{ border-bottom: 1px solid green;}
```

But there are several pixels between the second level `ul` and the `a` When I move the cursor to the second level ul, it disappears When the mouse is on the border of the a or on the margin of it. 
to explain my poor photoshop-less image:
red = margin, blue = padding, green=border
it is something similar to [Css Dropdown Menu - Hover disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199789/css-dropdown-menu-hover-disappear) but I need the gap for the designer. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: could you provide your css?

Comment: Yes but it is nested SASS, will "un-nest" and update the question asap

Comment: Just use codepen.io , it supports SASS

Comment: Or you can copy/paste the css generated by SASS

Comment: Basically you should wrap both hover elements with hover-wrappers, that are invisible, but helps with mouse interaction, worth reading: https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-menus-with-more-forgiving-mouse-movement-paths/ even though i would do this without line of javascript at all, there are several tricks like animation-delay > 0 to make it more user-friendly

Comment: You could easily do this without jquery anyway. http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=show-hide-dropdown-on-mouse-hover

Comment: pff can't get my sass to work on codepen sorry! http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGYqaz

Comment: @Vlad and what about the line below the text with the pixels above the line and below as offset for the 2nd level?

Comment: @MaciejKwas I'd upvote this, good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? Pure css without js

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/do3u59xx/1/)
[Update](http://jsfiddle.net/do3u59xx/2/)

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
ul > li {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

ul > li > a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px;
    background:#eee;
    border-bottom:1px solid #333;
    color:#333;
}

ul>li ul {
    opacity:0;
    width:200px;
    background:#333;
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    transition: all .3s ease .6s;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul>li:hover ul {
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
    transition: all .3s ease .1s;
}

ul>li li {
    float:none;
}

ul>li ul a {
    display:block;
    border:none;
    background:#333;
    color:#eee;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but there is no space between the 2nd level of the menu and the border of the first.

Comment: [Update](http://jsfiddle.net/do3u59xx/2/) - with a little effort you could do this by your own ;)

Comment: And if you add .subCatMenu{ position: relative; top: 20px; } is that ok ?

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud no it's not because nested div will get inside list flow thus will break it